# Scrollable container - Accessibility

Tags: usability, accessibility

we are hoping to use a scrollable container in the terms and condition section. The container is **NOT iframe** and we will make it with overflow hidden CSS.

I need your thoughts only from the **accessibility** point of view.

[image]

<sub>https://jelxty.axshare.com/checkout_t_c_2_2.html</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely fine as long as you make the container that scrolls focusable.

Add `tabindex="0"` to the container, check that you can focus it with <kbd>Tab</kbd> and ensure that once focused you can scroll with the arrow keys and you should have no problems if everything else is marked up correctly.